# Heimdall Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!

Tags: unbricking, device-firmware, heimdall

I have problem flashing my galaxy core SYSTEM with Heimdall using **system.img.ext4**

> ~/Desktop/lll$ sudo heimdall flash --SYSTEM
>   system.img.ext4  Heimdall v1.4.0
>
> Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
>
> This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution
>   is encouraged.
>
> If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
>   development please consider donating:
>
> Initialising connection... Detecting device... Claiming interface...
>   Attempt failed. Detaching driver... Claiming interface again...
>   Setting up interface...
>
> Initialising protocol... Protocol initialisation successful.
>
> Beginning session...
>
> Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond. Please be patient!
>
> Session begun.
>
> Downloading device's PIT file... PIT file download successful.
>
> Uploading SYSTEM
>   14%
>   ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
>   ERROR: SYSTEM upload failed!
>
> Ending session... ERROR: Failed to send end session packet! Releasing
>   device interface... Re-attaching kernel driver...

This is a log from my terminal.

I tried using older version of heimdall but had no success. Curently using v1.4.0 on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit version.

Firmware was downloaded from http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/3/?download=24508

---

After many times trying I went t friend to try it on Windows.

Unfortunately same error happens, it will fail when uploading system.
Also I tried heimdall on windows and same.

So this is not an error from heimdall side but something more deep.

---

Still trying

So now I tried with `verbose` argument

```
~/Desktop/lll/bbb$ sudo heimdall flash --verbose --no-reboot --SYSTEM system.img.ext4
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "Sasmsung"
           Product: "MSM7x27"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 82
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 01
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
Claiming interface again...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
WARNING: Control transfer #1 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #2 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #3 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #4 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #5 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #6 failed. Result: -9
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading SYSTEM
0%
1%

2%

3%

4%

5%

6%

7%

8%

9%

10%

11%

12%

13%

14%

15%
ERROR: libusb error -1 whilst receiving packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst receiving packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst receiving packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst receiving packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst receiving packet.

ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
ERROR: SYSTEM upload failed!

Ending session...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst sending packet. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -4 whilst sending packet.
ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
Releasing device interface...
Re-attaching kernel driver...
```

I also tried compiling newer version of libusb (1.0.18) with lastest heimdall  (1.4), also with older versions of heimdall. win7 32bit and 64bit, odin, heimdall-frontend, dancing around it, different ports of usb, different cables, different firmware.

I'm really desparate
Is there any support for bumping >.< I just dont have enough reputation to this question featured.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem, contemplating throwing away and buying a new one.  But mine was previously encrypted for work, flashed a new GoldenEye rom, and when I booted it asked me to decrypt the phone.  I put the old pw in but since the "answer" file was lost, the decrypt failed and the cellphone rebooted.  Same behavior when I put in a pw I KNEW was wrong.

So I have been Heimdall'ing my phone to get it back to Samsung S4 ATT LTE stock.  All the images pass but system.  System file is 2GB+ and heimdall reports that 100% was sent in less than 2 seconds so I know that isn't correct.

```
D:\DELETE\I337UCUAMDL_I337ATTAMDL_I337UCUAMDL_HOME>heimdall flash --SYSTEM syste
m.img.ext4 --verbose
Heimdall v1.4.0

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:


Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "Sasmsung"
           Product: "MSM8960"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 82
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 01
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
WARNING: Control transfer #1 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #2 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #3 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #4 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #5 failed. Result: -9
WARNING: Control transfer #6 failed. Result: -9
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading SYSTEM
0%
100%
ERROR: Failed to unpack received packet.

ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
ERROR: SYSTEM upload failed!

Ending session...
Rebooting device...
Releasing device interface...
```

---

I'm no longer getting prompted to input the decryption password, instead, I'm just looking at the Samsung Galaxy S4 page for ever. Factory reset also doesn't help.  System partition seems corrupted.  I need a real low level format or low level write to restore this partition.

Any advice?

---

Ok, I was desperate and it paid off.  I went back into LOKI, selected the master .tar.md5 and this time it worked.  Installed the system file without any problems and now I am no longer bricked.  The file I was using was:

http://stockroms.net/file/GalaxyS4/SGH-M919/SGH-M919-TMB-M919UVUAMDL-1366964131.zip
from:
galaxys4root . com / galaxy-s4-stock-firmware

The one marked: AT&T Galaxy S4 SGH-I337 UCUAMDL (Android 4.2.2) - Download (latest)

Comment: I'm not sure this is connected with my question. First of all, mine fails before 100% (about at 14%) and you had also different problems with initaizing control transfer (i guess). Also I can't access recovery because of bootloop.

Comment: nercrobumps kosher here? 2 seconds, 0-100%, system as well.  isch-545 going from rooted of1 to factory of1.  not sure if loki can help me, i have some loki, just not sure what you did with it, or what it does again.  does it repermiss core files or soemthing?